# a problem about quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $A\subset X$ is closed. Consider an equivalence relation on $X$ such that its classes are $A$ and $\{x\}$ for $x\in {X-A}$. Now we denote the induced quotient space by $X/A$. Prove that $X/A$ is hausdorff if $X$ is regular and it is normal if $X$ is normal.

I think we can say every pair of elements in $X/A$ could be separated by disjoint nbhds if both of them belongs to ${X-A}$ , because $X$ is regular and if one of them was $A$ then the statement is again true because $A\subset X$ is closed & $X$ is regular.

Am I right?
Is it really as easy as I said?

What can be done for the next part of the statement?

Hints are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed that easy, but you have to be careful that your open neighborhoods are really open in $X/A$. So if $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open neighborhoods around points in $X-A$, we can assume that both are subsets of $X-A$ since this set is open. Then $q[U]$ and $q[V]$ have preimages $U$ and $V$, respectively, hence they are open as $U$ and $V$ are open.

The second part is similar: If two closed disjoint sets in $X/A$ are represented by closed sets in $X-A$, the same reasoning as for points in $X-A$ gives the disjoint neighborhoods. If one of these sets contains $A$, then its preimage has $A$ as a subset, but they are still closed and disjoint, hence we can find disjoint open sets and these are open preimages.

Another approach is more general: We can show that the quotient map $q:X\to X/A$ is a closed (open) map if $A$ is closed (open). Now every closed continuous surjection preserves normality. Here *normal* means *disjoint closed sets have disjoint neighborhoods*, not necessarily Hausdorff. I'm used to the term $T_4$ for a space that is normal **and** Hausdorff.

Comment: Isn't $T_4$ a space that is normal and $T_1$? You wrote that it is normal and Hausdorff.

Comment: @Friedman: You may either define a $T_4$ space as a space that is normal and Hausdorff, or as a space that is normal and $T_1$. But each of these variants implies the other.

Comment: Oh yes sorry that makes sense... One direction is trivial and in the other you use equivalence of $T_1$ to singletons being closed and then separate them with normality.